# Accessing a JSON integer element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have an JSON-Object as follows:

Input for the months is
customerSend,customerReceived,totalSendAllCustomers,totalReceivedAllCustomers

```
var emailObj = {
                "kundenNummer":17889,
                "jahre":
                {
                    2017:{
                        "Januar":[15,30,75,125],
                        "Februar":[17,32,77,127],
                        "März":[19,34,79,129],
                    },
                    2018:{
                        "Januar":[28,12,66,198],
                        "Oktober":[40,4,40,5],
                    }
                }
        }
```

How exactly do I access the specific year?
I already tried it like this:

```
var keysYears = Object.keys(emailObj.jahre);
        var currentSelectedYear = keysYears[0];

        var keysMonth = Object.keys(emailObj.jahre[currentSelectedYear]);   
        var currentSelectedMonth = keysMonth[0];

        document.write(emailObj.jahre[currentSelectedYear].2017[0]);
```

I also tried some other ways of doing this but I already deleted those.

Can you tell me how to access the 2017 or 2018 data?
I know that I could convert them into strings but I want to know if I could also do it this way.

Comment: Do `emailObj.jahre['2017'].Januar[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the properties of your object `emailObj` by their names.

Either with a dot notation

```
emailObj.kundenNummer
```

Or by brackets notation

```
emailObj["kundenNummer"]
```

The dot notation won't work in your case because the name of your property is a number. You should then use

`emailObj.jahre["2017"]`

```js
var emailObj = {
  "kundenNummer": 17889,
  "jahre": {
    "2017": {
      "Januar": [15, 30, 75, 125],
      "Februar": [17, 32, 77, 127],
      "März": [19, 34, 79, 129],
    },
    "2018": {
      "Januar": [28, 12, 66, 198],
      "Oktober": [40, 4, 40, 5],
    }
  }
};

let year = "2017";
let month = "Januar";

console.log(emailObj.jahre[year][month]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a good clarification of when to use dots and when to use Brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `bracket` notation.

```
document.write(emailObj.jahre[currentSelectedYear][currentSelectedMonth][0]);
```

```js
var emailObj = {
                "kundenNummer":17889,
                "jahre":
                {
                    2017:{
                        "Januar":[15,30,75,125],
                        "Februar":[17,32,77,127],
                        "März":[19,34,79,129],
                    },
                    2018:{
                        "Januar":[28,12,66,198],
                        "Oktober":[40,4,40,5],
                    }
                }
        }
var keysYears = Object.keys(emailObj.jahre);
var currentSelectedYear = keysYears[0];
var keysMonth = Object.keys(emailObj.jahre[currentSelectedYear]);   
var currentSelectedMonth = keysMonth[0];
document.write(emailObj.jahre[currentSelectedYear][currentSelectedMonth][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a JavaScript object, the `key` is always a string, even if you use an integer **it will be converted into a string**.

```
obj = {
    key1: //contents
    key2: //contents
}
```

To access a specific key:

```
obj.key1
obj['key1']
```

For your example:

```
emailObj.jahre['2017']
emailObj['jahre']['2017']
```

Use the `for in` looping construct to loop through the keys of an object:

```
var emailObj = {
    "kundenNummer":17889,
    "jahre": {
        2017:{
            "Januar":[15,30,75,125],
            "Februar":[17,32,77,127],
            "März":[19,34,79,129],
        },
        2018:{
            "Januar":[28,12,66,198],
            "Oktober":[40,4,40,5],
        }
    }
}

for (key in emailObj.jahre) {
    console.log(emailObj.jahre[key]) //Here key will be '2017', '2018' etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access with dot notation properties which contain as name a number in JavaScript. Instead you should consider using bracket notation.

Example:

`emailObj.jahre['2017']`

```js
var emailObj = {
  "kundenNummer": 17889,
  "jahre": {
    2017: {
      "Januar": [15, 30, 75, 125],
      "Februar": [17, 32, 77, 127],
      "März": [19, 34, 79, 129],
    },
    2018: {
      "Januar": [28, 12, 66, 198],
      "Oktober": [40, 4, 40, 5],
    }
  }
};
console.log(emailObj['jahre']['2017']);
console.log(emailObj.jahre['2017']);
```